# iterate a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In code how can I access a list e.g "MyList" in sharepoint,
then iterate through this list items and get the value of a particular column on that list e.g the "URL" column?

Comment: Are you in a Feature / Web Part within your site? Or are you accessing SharePoint via the web services?

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve all items from a list and iterate through each one, the best solution would be as follows (assuming that this code is run as part of a feature):

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using(SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
    {
        SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["ListName"];
        SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

        foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
        {
            Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(listItem["Url"].ToString()) +"<BR>");
        }
    }
}
```

But if the list is very large, it would be better to paginate through the list items:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using(SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
    {
        SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["ListName"];

        if(items.ItemCount > 100)
        {        
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.RowLimit = 100;
            int index = 1;

            do
            {
                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

                foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
                {
                    Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(listItem["Url"].ToString()) +"<BR>");
                }

                query.ListItemCollectionPosition = items.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                index++;

            } while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
        }
        else
        {
            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

            foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
            {
                Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(listItem["Url"].ToString()) +"<BR>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is based on the Microsoft's [Best Practices for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

From [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20121029234721/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/):

The correct way to do it is to store the Items property return value in a SPListItemCollection variable. With this the database is only queried once and we will then iterate over the result set that is stored within the collection object. Here is the changed sample code:

```
SPListItemCollection items = SPContext.Current.List.Items;
for(int i=0;i<100 && i<items.Count;i++) {
  SPListItem listItem = items[i];
  htmlWriter.Write(listItem["Title"]);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to access a list not in the current context?

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate the items directly, and if you're using a URL field you probably want to use the `SPFieldUrlValue` class, so you don't have to deal with the way SharePoint stores URLs:

```
foreach(SPListItem item in spList.Items){
  SPFieldUrlValue data = item["Url"] as SPFieldUrlValue;
  // now you have data.Description, data.Url
}
```

There are many such `SPField*` helper classes, and they are very useful, specially when you have multiple values.

---

### Edit:

For some reason some people believe this way is slower, based on the evidence in the blog post of on Greg's post (even got down voted). This, however, has nothing to do with my answer: a `foreach` loop creates an Iterator, so it shouldn't access the database 99 more times (on the post they used a `for` loop to access the first 100 items).

Comment: If the list is large this technique will get you into trouble.  Ref. the Items collection results in all records associated with list to be retrieved from DB.  Not a problem unless the list is small.

Comment: Ok, this is very definitely the wrong way to iterate a Sharepoint list, as pointed out in the Microsoft best practices - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949.aspx#WorkingWithFoldersLists.  See this article for further details: http://lots-with-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/01/best-practices-sharepoint-object-model_6154.html  -1 for a poor answer.

Comment: @MagicAndi - Now, that's better, at least you downvote for a good reason. In fact, you can add that as an answer, since the OP did ask for a specific column.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this is NOT the correct answer. Linked articles don't really address this, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in a feature, the feature is activated at a specific scope, (e.g. Site, Web, WebApplication or Farm).

When you want to access a list from the feature, use the SPFeatureReceiver class to bind an event receiver to your feature. Then, in that class, there are overrides for when the feature activated event is triggered. that override receives a parameter of type SPFeatureReceiverProperties.

from that parameter, you can use get into a site:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
  using(SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite) //this depends on scope of feature
  {
    SPList myList = site.RootWeb.Lists["MyList"];
  }
}
```

for how the iterate that list, see the orther answers

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a very long time ago but I hope I am able to help someone out now :)

This is how I was able to accomplish this,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current domain 
        var current = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

        // We need to tell the SPSite object the URL of where our List is stored.
        // Make sure you have the right location placed after the 'current' variable
        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://"+current+"/DirectoryForLists/Lists")) 
        {
            // Returns the Web site that is located at the specified server-relative or site-relative URL.
            using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                //Get our list we created.
                SPList list = spWeb.Lists["Name Of the List"];

                // Create a new SPQuery object that will hold our CAML query.
                SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
                // CAML query.
                // This allows you to controll how you receieve your data.
                // Make the data ASC or DESC. Find more on MSDN.
                q.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='DESCR' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";

                // We put our list data into a SP list Item Collection.
                // Notice that the CAML query is the only parameter for the GetItems() function.
                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(q);

                // Here you can loop through your list.
                foreach (SPListItem spItem in items)
                {
                    // Your code here.
                    MessageBox(spItem);

                    // Get URL column
                    MessageBox(spItem["URL"]);

                    // Another Column
                    MessageBox(spItem["DateTime"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you down vote me, tell me why. This solution actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best option to iterate

```
    SPList list = web.Lists[listname];

    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy>";
    //Scope="Recursive" retrieves items from all folders and subfolders in a list
    query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='" + Lists.MRPLibrary.RebateClaimed + "' /><FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
    query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";
    query.RowLimit = 100;

    do
    {
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        foreach (SPListItem listItem in items)
        {

        }

        query.ListItemCollectionPosition = items.ListItemCollectionPosition;

    } while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code used to delete all bulk list items and here can skip latest 150 items to delete.
Iterating through SPListItemCollection and very quick time like 3000 items will be delete in 2 mints.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["DemoDelete"];

SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems();
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + watch);
//delete all items uncomment this code
//foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
//{
//    SPListItem delItem = list.GetItemById(item.ID);
//    Console.WriteLine("Item Deleted" + delItem.ID);
//    delItem.Delete();
//    list.Update();
//}
//skip lastest 150 items
for (int i = collListItems.Count - 150; i >= 0; i--)
{
SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(collListItems[i].ID);  //collListItems[i];
Console.WriteLine("Item Deleted" + listItem.ID);
listItem.Delete();
list.Update();
}

watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.WriteLine("End Time: " + elapsedMs);
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, you shouldn´t iterate the Items collection directly (especially in large collections). Here´s an alternaltive:

// if you need the whole collection. Otherwise use SPQuery on the list

```
DataTable dt = list.Items.GetDataTable();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
 ...
```

Then you can do numerous things. If you need to do a check to get only some of the items, ex:

```
   if (row["ContentType"].ToString().Equals("Your contenttype id"))
   {
   SPListItem item = list.GetItemById((int)row["ID"]);
```

or use the SpQuery to get your column in the query, like:

```
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='UrlColumn'/>";

list.Items.GetItems(oQuery).GetDataTable();

...foreach code...
row["UrlColumn"]
```

Comment: This offers no benefits over iterating the items collection. The problem is still that you get all columns and all rows. Even worse is that datasets are bloated.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in a x86 environment I've recently discovered an awesomely read-only way to get at the data with MSSQL/OLEDB...

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://sharepoint.lsi.local/ops/;LIST={3DCAF100-44A1-4331-8328-748AA98E36AB};',
    'SELECT * FROM list'
)
```

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint

Answer (score -1):

BTW
When using OPENROWSET...

IMEX=2 is for Read/Write. IMEX=1 is ReadOnly.

List = [Name] works for me instead of needing to use the list={GUID}.