# How can I access a sharepoint url-based directory from C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, directory

I can access the sharepoint folder by putting this url into a file explorer:

```
http://wss.sharepointsite.com/sites/tech/Lists/email/Attachments
```

If I put that in a browser, it just redirects me back to the tech main page.

I tried this and just got a "path not in correct format" error.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("http://wss.sharepointsite.com/sites/tech/Lists/email/Attachments");
```

I need to be able to be able to iterate through each folder and file to create a database for searching.

Comment: I believe you may need to look into Sharepoint API CSOM and make calls using the API.  There are methods for iterating over a Sharepoint list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iterate a sharepoint list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965695/iterate-a-sharepoint-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PowerShell script with SharePoint Online CSOM library to download attachments for a list:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
Function Download-ListAttachments()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $DownloadDirectory
    )   
   Try {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Cred = Get-Credential
        $Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
     
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred
 
        #Get All Items from the List
        $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
         
        #Create download directory if it doesn't exist
        If (!(Test-Path -path $DownloadDirectory))       
        {           
            New-Item $DownloadDirectory -type directory         
        }
         
        #Iterate through each list item
        Foreach($Item in $ListItems)
        {
            #Get All attachments from the List Item
            $AttachmentsColl = $Item.AttachmentFiles
            $Ctx.Load($AttachmentsColl)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
            #Get attachment for each list item
            ForEach($Attachment in $AttachmentsColl)
            {
                #Download attachment
                $FileContent = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($Ctx, $Attachment.ServerRelativeUrl)
                $FileName= $DownloadDirectory+$Item.id.ToString()+"_"+$Attachment.FileName
                $FileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($FileName)
                $FileContent.Stream.CopyTo($FileStream)
                $FileStream.Close()
           }
        }
 
        write-host  -f Green "List Attachments Downloaded Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Downloading List Attachments!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/"
$ListName="Projects"
$DownloadDirectory="C:\Temp\"
 
#Call the function to copy list items
Download-ListAttachments -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName -DownloadDirectory $DownloadDirectory
```

In the download folder, it will have the subfolders with "1,2,3,4..." which stands for the ListItem Id:

[image]

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Download Attachments from List using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-download-attachments-from-list-using-powershell.html)